# How to most efficiently avoid ValueError when running str(), int(), float(), etc, on user input

Tags: python-3.x

I want to simplify the tests and control flow to check if user input is the right type of data before running either str() or int() on it.

I have already worked out the start of this. It's just incomplete and probably inefficient. This is actually a function inside of a user_prompt function I have, and this is the "form_check()" part, which is really what the topic concerns, so I left the rest of the code out.

```
# the following is run on input from the user = indata
# with a string telling the user what type of data to give = req
def form_check(req, indata):
    if "int" in req:
        req = "int"
        if indata.isnumeric():
            print(req)
            return int(indata)
        else:
            exit(1)
    elif "str" in req:
        req = "str"
        if indata.isalnum():
            print(req)
            return str(indata)
        else:
            exit(1)
    elif "list" in req:
        req = "list"
        if indata.startswith("(") and indata.endswith(")"):
            print(req)
            return list(indata) # I know this isn't right but need to research; lists and dicts are new to me still
        else:
            exit(1)
    else:
        print("fail")
        exit(1)
```

from my output...

```
>  USER: Prompting user for a number
                        Give input as integer
> 3243432
int
>  USER: Prompting user for your name
                        Give input as string
> sdfsaf243
str
>  USER: Prompting user for whatever
                        Give input as list
> (SDf)
list
3243432 sdfsaf243 ['(', 'S', 'D', 'f', ')']
```

As you can see from the output, this code passes and doesn't error but it only begins to address what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only str, float and int are necessary here. `input` always returns a string. Therefore, all inputs can be turned into a list by splitting into characters. You can use a try/except for int/float and use `str` as a fallback:

```
def form_check(req, data):
    if req in (int, 'int'):
        try:
            return int(data)
        except ValueError:
            exit(1)
    elif req in (float, 'float'):
        try:
            return float(data)
        except ValueError:
            exit(1)
    return str(data)
```

However, if you are calling `exit(1)` for a bad input, it’s more beneficial to the user to raise a proper exception like `ValueError('input must be convertible to "int"')` to let the user know why the program failed.

If you want the user to input a list of values, it’s probably better to ask them to input comma-separated values and then return:

```
[item.strip() for item in data.split(',')]
```

Comment: `if req in (x, 'x')` -- What is this syntax called, where the conditional statement is given as... is that a tuple? What is that saying? "in the variable x, and the string of the variable?" or is that more like, "the x form of string x?"

Comment: It means that you can either type `form_check(float, ...)` or `form_check('float', ...)`. The one without the quotes around it refers to the actual float data type. It’s just for convenience and saves you having to type the string with quotes.

Comment: `if req in (x, 'x')` means if x equals either of those values. It’s a quick way of writing `if req == x or req == 'x'`. The way this works is by creating a tuple (container) of the 2 possibilities and checks whether `req` is one of the values _in_ the container.

Comment: Is it accurate to say that all things contained in parentheses and  separated by ", " are tuples? for instance, every set of arguments given to any function is a tuple as well?

Comment: I need to learn to implement try and except. I haven't read those chapters yet, but it seems like that is mainly it. I more or less get what its for if i haven't read the technicality of how to use it yet. I'm still on page 184/328 in LP3THW. Classes are blowing my mind and I should probably read something simpler like that. Thank you.

Comment: That’s partly accurate. You don’t technically need parentheses for it to be a tuple. `1, 2` is the same as `(1, 2)`. The commas are what make it a tuple. Even `(12,)` is a tuple as it has a comma. I suppose function arguments are tuples - that also explains why `*args` creates a tuple

Comment: Try and except is incredibly useful to reduce your code and handle errors. Wrapping `int(x)` in a `try/except ValueError` is much easier than checking the digits manually. It also allows you to provide custom written errors to users rather than generic ones like `KeyError: x`.